# pytest-asyncio has a closed event loop, but only when running all tests

Tags: pytest, python-asyncio, pytest-asyncio

I have a test to verify an exception is thrown from an async response, which I'm using pytest-asyncio version 0.10.0 to run.

Code is basically:

```
class TestThis:
    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    def test_the_thing(self):
       arg1 = "cmd"
       arg2 = "second command"
       with pytest.raises(CustomException):
           await do_thing(arg1, arg2)
```

Now the really weird thing is this test works fine if I run it alone, or if I run the class alone.  However when I run all tests (pytest at the project root), it fails every time with a runtime error, saying the loop is closed.

Comment: Do you close the loop in another test?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @dirn - no, this is the only async test in the suite

Comment: So, not necessarily an answer, but the test was living in a subfolder of the tests folder

Moving the test from services to the root tests, it now works?

Comment: This might help you: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-asyncio/issues/30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also happen if you are using a teardown fixture that does the cleanup before yield

E.g.

```
async def teardown():

  # cleanup stuff involving async
  ..

  yield
```

On the second test this will fail, since each test case gets a different async loop, and thus the teardown will try to access the loop of the previous test but that has already been destroyed.

The fix is to put the cleanup after `yield`

```
async def teardown():
  yield

  # cleanup stuff involving async
  ..
```

This ensures the cleanup happens in the same async loop

Answer (score 22):

I had to tweak @matthewpark319's answer a bit, but adding a `session`-scoped fixture in `conftest.py` worked.

```py
import asyncio

import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def event_loop():
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    except RuntimeError:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()
```

If you're using `pytest-asyncio`, you may also need to edit your `pyproject.toml` and add:

```ini
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
asyncio_mode = "auto"
```

Comment: `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` yields a `DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop` on Python 3.10. https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop

Comment: I do not know why, but this solution works only not for all my projects.

Comment: I logged just to upvote this one :)

Comment: Why isn't this a bug in pytest-asyncio?

Answer (score 11):

https://pypi.org/project/pytest-asyncio/

You can apparently override pytest-asyncio's version of the event loop fixture. They have it like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def event_loop():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()
```

I have it like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def event_loop():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    yield loop
    cleanly_shutdown(loop)
```

Or in other cases like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def event_loop():
    yield asyncio.get_event_loop()

def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    asyncio.get_event_loop().close()
```

These docs are very helpful: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html?highlight=sessionfinish#pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionfinish

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a very similar, if not the same, problem. (Pytest failed with "loop closed" only if I ran *all* the tests). The solution for me was different, so I thought I'd post it.

At the top of my conftest.py file I had:

```
    @pytest.fixture(params=["asyncio"], scope="session")
    def anyio_backend(request):
        return request.param

    # AsyncClient comes from HTTPX and "app" is FastAPI
    @pytest.fixture(scope="session")
    async def client() -> AsyncIterator[AsyncClient]:
        async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://testserver") as client:
            yield client
```

If I ran tests in a single module at a time (or in VSCode's test plugin) everything went fine. But if I ran all my tests via pytest terminal command, everything would pass and then I would get... THIS:

```
__________________________________________________ ERROR at teardown of TestValidations.test_validate_url_with_malformed_or_altered_token[asyncio] ___________________________________________________

anyio_backend = 'asyncio', args = (), kwargs = {}, backend_name = 'asyncio', backend_options = {}, runner = <anyio._backends._asyncio.TestRunner object at 0x1049eaad0>

    def wrapper(*args, anyio_backend, **kwargs):  # type: ignore[no-untyped-def]
        backend_name, backend_options = extract_backend_and_options(anyio_backend)
        if has_backend_arg:
            kwargs["anyio_backend"] = anyio_backend
    
        with get_runner(backend_name, backend_options) as runner:
            if isasyncgenfunction(func):
>               yield from runner.run_asyncgen_fixture(func, kwargs)

../../Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/ab-bJoznT_5-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/pytest_plugin.py:68: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
../../Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/ab-bJoznT_5-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py:2097: in run_asyncgen_fixture
    self._loop.run_until_complete(fixture_task)
../../.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py:628: in run_until_complete
    self._check_closed()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=True debug=False>

    def _check_closed(self):
        if self._closed:
>           raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
E           RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

../../.pyenv/versions/3.11.4/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py:519: RuntimeError
```

Ugh.

### Solution

The problem was rooted in the session-scoped `client`. I changed it to "module" scope and all was fixed! No need to manually mess with event loops.

```
    @pytest.fixture(params=["asyncio"], scope="session")
    def anyio_backend(request):
        return request.param

    # AsyncClient comes from HTTPX and "app" is FastAPI
    @pytest.fixture(scope="module")
    async def client() -> AsyncIterator[AsyncClient]:
        async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://testserver") as client:
            yield client
```

I'm not sure if it's because I wasn't explicitly cleaning up after the `yield` or perhaps HTTPX was closing the loop before anyio. (I'd welcome some insight from anyone more experienced than I.)

For anyone encountering this issue in the future, I'd recommend considering fixture scopes - perhaps it will save you from needing to play with event loops.

Answer (score 0):

After implementing two highest score solutions. I am still facing the problem.

I finally use asyncio to run the test, instead of using `@pytest.mark.asyncio`:

```py
def test_query_database():
    async def query_database():
        ...

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(query_database())
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, what worked was to use [aiounittest](https://aiounittest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asynctestcase.html) and define my own **get_event_loop** as suggested there.