# RuntimeError: Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am using **aiohttp**, **asyncio** and **codetiming** to make concurrent requests. I've recently upgraded Python to version 3.9.0 and I'm getting a RuntimeError: Event loop is closed after the program has runs.
I am tring to make asynchronous requests using queue data structure...

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from codetiming import Timer
async def task(name, work_queue):
    timer = Timer(text=f"Task {name} elapsed time: {{:.1f}}")
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while not work_queue.empty():
            url = await work_queue.get()
            print(f"Task {name} getting URL: {url}")
            timer.start()
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                await response.text()
            timer.stop()
async def main():
    # Create the queue of work
    work_queue = asyncio.Queue()
    # Put some work in the queue
    for url in [
        "http://google.com",
        "http://yahoo.com",
        "http://linkedin.com",
        "http://apple.com",
        "http://microsoft.com",
        "http://facebook.com",
        "http://twitter.com",
    ]:
        await work_queue.put(url)

    # Run the tasks
    with Timer(text="\nTotal elapsed time: {:.1f}"):
        await asyncio.gather(
            asyncio.create_task(task("One", work_queue)),
            asyncio.create_task(task("Two", work_queue)),
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I also get my valid result but I don't know why I get this RunTime Error.
The output is follows:

```
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000020634355E50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000020634355E50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000020634355E50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000020634355E50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000020634355E50>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asyncio throws runtime error with exception ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68123296/asyncio-throws-runtime-error-with-exception-ignored)

Answer (score 29):

Try using `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())`
instead of `asyncio.run(main())`

Comment: If anybody else comes here, this also works with sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio

Comment: Excellent - can you perhaps explain what it is that `.run_until_complete(main())` does that `.run()` doesn't do, which explains why this resolves the issue?

Comment: I have to also suggest explaining why `.run_until_complete(main())` fixes the issue. In Python 3.7+, [using `asyncio.run()` is preferred](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), so I'm confused by this answer.

Comment: [Deprecated since version 3.10: Deprecation warning is emitted if there is no running event loop. In future Python releases, this function will be an alias of get_running_loop().](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop)

Comment: This appears to have solved my problem, similar to what is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61022713/pytest-asyncio-has-a-closed-event-loop-but-only-when-running-all-tests

Comment: In python 3.10+ it's deprecated. So what is the correct way to do it now?

Comment: This is a workaround. asynаcio.run is overall better, because it handles the shutdown well (e.g. cancels the remaining tasks).

Comment: @Krrkrkrkr

loop = ```loop = asyncio.new_event_loop();
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop);
loop.run_until_complete(main())```

Comment: Don't forget to do it in every async call in your program. This was the solution for me, thanks