# RuntimeError: Event loop is closed while trying to run an https request using aiohttp

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am using asyncio and aiohttp to run following asyncronous code but getting this weird error called RuntimeError: Event loop is closed. Though I am getting the desirable results but I am not getting the reason behind this error. I have searched the whole internet but couldent find any relavent resources. I have tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65682221/runtimeerror-exception-ignored-in-function-proactorbasepipetransport) , but it didnt work for me.

`

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time

start_time = time.time()


async def get_pokemon(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        pokemon = await resp.json()
        return pokemon['name']


async def main():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

        tasks = []
        for number in range(1, 15):
            url = f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{number}'
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_pokemon(session, url)))

        original_pokemon = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for pokemon in original_pokemon:
            print(pokemon)

asyncio.run(main())
```

`
My error message

```
    RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000000002BCCEB80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python 38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Python 38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Python 38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Python 38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
```

It would be really great if someone can help me with this.
Thanks