# asyncio throws runtime error with exception ignored

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Below is a simple program to collect URL lengths.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from time import perf_counter


URLS = ['http://www.cnn.com', 'http://www.huffpost.com', 'http://europe.wsj.com',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk', 'http://failfailfail.com']

async def async_load_url(url, session):
    try:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            content = await resp.read()
        print(f"{url!r} is {len(content)} bytes")
    except IOError:
        print(f"failed to load {url}")        

async def main():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [async_load_url(url, session) for url in URLS]
        await asyncio.wait(tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(main())
    elapsed = perf_counter() - start
    print(f"\nTook {elapsed} seconds")
```

Why is the following code failing with a runtime error with exception ignored in python 3.9? How to fix it?

Traceback is: `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed` specifically with `Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001F8A7A713A0>`

Comment: Is it a runtime error? Or is it a warning? It probably wants you to do something with the tasks returned by `asyncio.wait`.

Comment: Please update the question to include the traceback.

Comment: Looks like you're on Windows, in which case this is a known issue in aiohttp https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4324

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by a known issue in aiohttp on Windows, for details check out the bug at https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4324

There are a couple of hacks that silence this error. The first way is to get the event loop and call `run_until_complete` instead of `asyncio.run(main())` like so:

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Alternatively, changing the event loop policy to `WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy` before calling `asyncio.run(main())` also works as the problem seems to occur when using `WindowsProtractorEventLoopPolicy`.

```
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
asyncio.run(main())
```

Of course, the second solution will make your code platform specific, so be careful.

Answer (score -1):

You are using `asyncio.await` to run all your tasks, but you are not checking the completed tasks for exceptions. `await` returns two sequences: one with the completed tasks, one with the pending tasks - you have to query the done tasks for exceptions:

```py
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [asyncio.task(async_load_url(url, session), name=url) for url in URLS]
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks)
        for task in done:
            try:
                task.exception() # in task execption is re-raised
            except Exception as exc:
                print (f"Exception loading url {task.name}:\n {exc}")
```

If it is a long process and you want to handle exceptions as they happen, [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) offers an interface that facilitates that - just tell it when it should return:

```py
        
    async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [asyncio.task(async_load_url(url, session), name=url) for url in URLS]
        while tasks:
            done, tasks = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION)
            for task in done:
                try:
                    task.exception() # in task execption is re-raised
                except Exception as exc:
                    print (f"Exception loading url {task.name}:\n {exc}")
```

Comment: The exception is not raised by the tasks. They are raised when the event loop is closed and the event loop objects are deleted when their reference count drops to zero. Arguably this is a bug in the Protractor loop `__del__` implementation for not verifying that it is already closed before trying to execute any remaining callbacks but no amount of task exception checking will fix this.