# pytest-asyncio has a closed event loop, but only when running all tests again

Tags: loops, events, pytest, python-asyncio

I have exactly the same issue with [pytest-asyncio has a closed event loop, but only when running all tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61022713/pytest-asyncio-has-a-closed-event-loop-but-only-when-running-all-tests)
(I couldn't comment there..)

```py
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/asyncio/connection.py", line 729, in disconnect
    self._writer.close()  # type: ignore[union-attr]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/streams.py", line 337, in close
    return self._transport.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 706, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 753, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

I don't still understand why it happened..

I almost fixed the issue with the solution @RobinFrcd suggested. But somehow it worked only pytest-asyncio==0.20.3 When I upgraded pytest-asyncio version to the recent 0.23.5 then the event loop was closed again.

When I used pytest-asyncio==0.23.5 version and changed event_loop fixture to class it seemed to work but failed again while the Redis class was running.

I expected all tests to run well not only single running but also CI test.

UPDATE:

I added this event_loop fixture in conftest.

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def event_loop():
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    except RuntimeError:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()
```

and run tests like the below code.

```py
@pytest.mark.asyncio
class TestRedisWS:
       async def test_ws_connection(self, ..):
        ...
```

if you think it isn't enough information let me know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.